# XML Validation c# - Complex Type

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm extracting some xml from an XFA static form.
Here is a sample:

```
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
<xfa:data>
<frmMain>
<InspectionDate>19/02/2012</InspectionDate>
<ENID>111114567</ENID>
<EmployeeNumber>1234</EmployeeNumber>
<GroundType>
   <value>Tarmac</value>
   <value>Concrete</value>
</GroundType>
<Width>800</Width>
<Height>900</Height>
<OtherDetails>Corssing of x road and y street</OtherDetails>
</frmMain>
</xfa:data>
</xfa:datasets>
```

I use Windows SDK 7.0 utility Xsd.exe to generate a schema so I can validate that XML against
Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="datasets" targetNamespace="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xmlns:mstns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:attribute name="dataNode" msdata:Prefix="xfa" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="datasets" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US" msdata:Prefix="xfa">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="data" msdata:Prefix="xfa">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="frmMain" form="unqualified">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="InspectionDate" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ENID" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="EmployeeNumber" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="Width" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="Height" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="OtherDetails" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="GroundType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute ref="mstns:dataNode" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I use XmlReaderSettings with a XmlReader to read and validate the Xml against the Xsd. Everything is ok as long as I do not have a complex type. But in this case I have.

What can be done?

And the Error I'm getting is:

The element 'GroundType' cannot contain child element 'value' because the parent element's content model is empty.

Comment: Your question is not clear; what is it that it is not OK, what particular error or unexpected behaviour do you see?

Comment: I have just added the error, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GroundType definition should look like this:

```
<xs:element name="GroundType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="value" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="mstns:dataNode"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks it's all working, it's a shame that Xsd.exe does not do that by default!